# What is Data Virtualization?

Tags: replication, backup, restore, virtualisation, daas

I've just been asked whether our company should consider `Data Virtualization` for our test environments.  The benefits are given as:

- Screening of sensitive data
- Fast data refreshes in our test environments
- Potential benefits for DR and BI scenarios

However I've only found marketing info; nothing technical.  From what I can figure out there are 2 approaches:

- A service layer over a production database which abstracts you from the data model (presumably resulting in a different data model presented by that new layer).
- A tool to automate the restore and subsequent manipulation of data which can be used by non-technical users and is faster than using database backups and SQL scripts.

Without seeing any technical information this smells of snake oil to me; but I want to understand it rather than dismissing out of hand.

---

Keywords:
[data-as-a-service] 
[data-virtualisation] 
[data-virtualization] 
[delphix] 
[denodo]

Comment: Which of the three "benefits" above can you not perform at the moment? Virtualisation is a bit of a buzzword at the moment. I've yet to be convinced by all of the "snake oil" as you so eloquently put it. Not that there can't be other [benefits](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-benefits-of-virtualization-in-the-data-center/) (or [here](http://www.vmware.com/virtualization/how-it-works))

Comment: At present we don't have a real problem; we have scripts to refresh data in our test environments which we're looking to improve, and we use replication (SQL Server with dedicated distributor) to feed BI with a copy of our production data for monitoring and reporting (via some ETL) which works but requires care when making schema-affecting changes, and can suffer poor performance at peak times.  My manager had a sales call and asked if it could help with the above.  My advice was to ignore this as we have bigger problems; but wanted to get a better understanding to confirm (or otherwise) this.

Comment: NB: This is not the same as server virtualisation (for that I can understand the benefit; particularly where servers peak use times complement one anothers).  Rather this seems to be billed as automated data refresh (e.g. to data what puppet/chef are for platforms), but the word `virtualisation` seems inappropriate if it's more of an `automation` / `workflow` / `script generator` tool; and there's other parts which don't seem to fit with that concept making me assume I've missed something.

Comment: The best resource I've found so far is: https://dantehranian.wordpress.com/2015/01/13/solve-the-devops-gap-deploy-fresh-app-data-in-test-environments/ - which sells it well, but again lacks the detail for me to think "ah, that would work for us!".

Comment: My concept is that it's a case of Cap-ex vs. Op-ex. This means that you (probably) have to go cloud also - otherwise, the financial efficiencies are not optimal - i.e. the principle of self-service in line with demand isn't achieved. Try out a virtual machine in the cloud (AWS is one example). That would be my advice - put one of your test servers up first and see how that works out for you. AFAICS, many businesses are gradually adopting these offerings - but like anything, there are pluses and minuses. [This](http://www.sysprobs.com/disadvantages-virtualization-opinion) echos my point.

Comment: @Vérace I think the OP is referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_virtualization, it's new for me too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data virtualization is the provision of an abstraction layer so the data consumer does not have to know the physical location or format of the original data. You may have a PostGres DB, a MySQL DB, a SQL Server DB, a whole batch of Parquet/ORC files and the person writing the query is completely unaware of that physicality. As far as they are concerned they are hitting a connection to Presto (or whatever data virtualization solution you'd chosen use).

Technologies such as Apache Presto allow a central point against which to run SQL queries but Presto itself is configured to know where and what the source data is, the end user does not need to know.  Presto is an open-source tool that has had a lot of input from Teradata, particularly with regard to JDBC connectivity, security and LDAP authentication.  It also has commercial support from StarBurst.  Starburst has recently announced a cost based query optimizer for Presto.

AWS have faith in Presto because they have based AWS Athena on it.  The beauty of it is that data does not have to reside in a relational database.  It can be file based as well.

In terms of screening sensitive data you can choose who has access to what but it isn't a data masking or obfuscation tool.

It isn't snake oil but neither is it a silver bullet.  There is obviously a hit on the source systems and you have to understand what that hit is.  The key benefit is that you don't have to shift data all over the place and have a huge plethora of technology to support that data movement.

Comment: Thank-you.  So is the idea that you have this as a middleware between the your app and the "real database", where you can point certain queries at mock tables / something like that?  i.e. I understand that Presto allows you to present multiple sources under one wrapper; but how does that relate to data virtualization / what is data virtualization?

Comment: Data virtualisation is the provision of an abstraction layer so the data consumer does not have to know the physical location or format of the original data.  You may have a PostGres DB, a MySQL DB, a SQL Server DB, a whole batch of Parquet/ORC files and the person writing the query is completely unaware of that physicality.  As far as they are concerned they are hitting a connection to Presto.  Presto acts as a Data Virtualisation solution.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @DavePoole.  I guess the context in which I'd heard it had thrown me; i.e. as people were talking about using it in the sense of improving our test environment's data refreshes (speed & security); which I can see this could help with in various ways, but isn't the main focus of this concept.  Thank-you.

Comment: In terms of refreshing a test environment it depends on who has access to that test environment.  If you have the concept of AS-LIVE/PRODUCTION environments then you could use data virtualisation as an escrow method of refreshing the environment.  Your data virtualisation solution has access to production, your refresh job has access to your data virtualisation and there is no need/risk from connecting test environments to production environments.

Comment: I classify data into "Data that can be copied from live", "Data that must be obfuscated" and "Data that must be generated in non-production environments".  GDPR makes me nervous about copied data that is anything other than reference data.  Personally I would put reference data under source control rather than have a means of copying it between environments.

Comment: Perfect; and fully agree with your comments on reference data vs obfuscated vs safe.  I'd add 1 more category which is "environment specific"; e.g. things like database connection strings and UNC paths, where the address/value is different for each environment and must remain unaffected by the refresh.  For those I'd also manage under source control, only with any sensitive information (keys/credentials) replaced with tokens which can be substituted by scripts reading this info from our secrets manager.